# Is it possible to make an SR latch using XOR gates only?

Tags: digital-logic

Due to certain rules, I can only use components available to me, so I cannot implement an SR latch using the standard NOR or NAND configurations readily available online. If it is possible, please may you explain how one might go about doing so.

Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Seems like this is an academic question, also you haven't even listed the components available to you.

Comment: You could technically do it but your output would be rather slow.

Comment: @KingDuken Can you explain how?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I thought about typing out the formulas but there's actually an answer on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-XOR-gate-be-used-to-make-other-logic-gates-If-no-why-not) about it :) The SR latch using only XOR gates would probably be really large and the performance would suck but I don't think it's impossible.

Comment: @KingDuken That is doing tricks with wired gates and assumptions of open-drain implementation. In general XOR is not functionally complete, therefore other gates can't be implemented using (only) it. That said, there might be some trick to create some kind of latch, but I can't think of any.

Comment: @EugeneSh. With enough DeMorgan Theorem manipulation and open drain trickery, I'm sure you can make an entire ALU out of XOR gates LOL :)

Comment: @KingDuken Open drain trickery might be the key, but again it is not a pure mathematical XOR.

Comment: an XOR gate is linear (the logic meaning of linearity, not the continuous function meaning), you need non-linear gates to make a latch, so without other trickery, like implementing an AND or OR function by tying outputs with tailored drive strengths together, or just implementing diode resistor logic at the outputs, it's easy to prove it's not possible just from the linearity argument.

Answer (score 1):

Not if we follow the normal logic design assumptions that each input will be fed by either a constant value or by exactly one output.

The problem is to make a SR latch we need to be able to force the output of a gate to a particular state, XOR gates can't do that, whatever the value of input A is, the output still depends on the value of input B.

If our logic family allows for "wired or" or "wired and" then it is possible. At that point we can basically use our XOR gates as buffers and inverters and use the "wired or" or "wired and" to perform the actual logic operations.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit can be a 2-input OR, NOR, AND or NAND gate depending on the input strapping. You can figure out which is which.

As others have hinted it's slow because of the resistor pull-down, probably in the 100ns
range with the values shown.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIFfmZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A similar thing could be done on a chip without diodes and resistor if the P-channel transistors were made much stronger than the N-channel (or vice-versa with a mirrored circuit). The speed penalty vs. power consumption would be more favorable in that case because the capacitance on chip is much  less, but it still would be very undesirable.

Comment: An OR gate made with diodes and resistors hardly counts as "using XOR gates only".

Comment: @DaveTweed  XOR **is** the only kind of gate used. The other parts are passive. Depends on how you parse the question. I chose to parse it so there was an (possibly) interesting answer instead of the obvious "it's impossible".

Comment: A gate is a gate, regardless of the implementation technology. "Gate" is not limited to what you find on SSI ICs.

Comment: @DaveTweed  Is a wired-or a gate?

Comment: Yes, of course!